# how can I use Solr to do real-time search

Tags: lucene, solr, real-time, near-real-time

now we use deltaImport to update data from db to index. 
but we have some information need a real-time search or near real-time search.
what should I do if I use solr to solve this?

Comment: sorry,  I will do that right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to generate near real-time-search i would update the data in small packages and also update the index in small packages every minute (index update needs only some seconds - depending on the size of new data)

don't forget to optimize the index regularly

Answer (score 1):

This post could be useful for you: [Solr and Near Real-Time Search](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/04/09/solr-dev-diary-solr-and-near-real-time-search/)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Solr 3.3 with RankingAlgorithm 1.2. It supports NRT and can update 10,000 docs / sec. You can search concurrently during the updates. You can get more information from here:

http://solr-ra.tgels.org/wiki/en/Near_Real_Time_Search_ver_3.x